# windows command promt zip/compress directory

Tags: archive, cmd, compression

Is possible to compress/archive a directory with all of its sub-directories and files in a single file from cmd.exe ? I know there are a lot of utilities available but I need to perform the operation only with the windows default utilities . I'm running windows server 2003 .

Comment: I know about makecab but I think it doesn't keep the directory tree ....correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Did you try my (very old) answer?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f

Answer (score 2):

Although the old makecab doesn't store a real directory structure, you can command the output directories for each file if you really need it. The procedure is more cumbersome than using a modern utility, but can be done.

For doing this you should create a .ddf file.

The manual for the old makecab has been removed from the web by MS. I found a copy [here](http://am.net/lib/tools/Microsoft/cab-sdk/DOCS/).

In page 33 of the makecab manual you will find:

`DestinationDir=path`
`Path prefix to store in cabinet file for each file in the cabinet.`
`Default:   .Set DestinationDir=        ; Default is no path prefix`

**path**`is concatenated with a path separator (“\”) and the target file name on`
`File Copy Commands to produce the file name that is stored in cabinet file.` 
`EXTRACT.EXE will use this file name as the default name when the file is extracted.`

```
Examples:  
.Set DestinationDir=SYSTEM  ; Following files get SYSTEM prefix      
bin\ARIAL.TTF           ; Name in cabinet is SYSTEM\ARIAL.TTF  
.Set DestinationDir=        ; No prefix  
bin\ARIAL.TTF           ; Name in cabinet is ARIAL.TTF
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

There's really very little you can do as there's no command-line compression as part of Windows as standard.

The closest thing I can think of is to use the backup program [NTBackup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490952.aspx).

If there's any way you can install a utility I'd strongly recommend [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) which I've had good experience of scripting with.

Comment: I'm very new in windows administration. Can you please help me with a quick syntax to "compress"(although I understand that it doesn't compress/archive) a directory with all its sub-directories in a single file ?  on linux I simply use tar -cvzf file.tar directory