# Using MakeCab.exe & .ddf file (i.e. using directive file) how to specify destination cab filename?

Tags: windows, compression, cmd, cab

I have decided to use `makecab.exe` for my requirement to create cab files in my application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#microsoftmakecabusersguide

And I need to store files as per given path whether relative or absolute inside cab and extract files with original path preserved. So I will be using directive file for this and give that input to makecab command.

[windows command promt zip/compress directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266378/windows-command-promt-zip-compress-directory/3274497#3274497)

But the cab output is stored in folder Disk1\1.cab.

**Please help me to know how can I specify a desired cab filename as destination (I will take cab file name from user input)?**

**Also, is it possible to append more files to existing cab file in second run of makecab command?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

You can set following two variables in the directive file which will identify destination path and name of cab file:

`DiskDirectoryTemplate=template` [Output directory name template; * is replaced by disk number]
`CabinetNameTemplate=template`   [Cabinet file name template; * is replaced by Cabinet number]

Description from [Microsoft MakeCAB User's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#microsoftmakecabusersguide)

> **DiskDirectoryTemplate**=template
>
> Set the output directory name template. One directory is created for
>   each disk of the layout.
>
> Default: .Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=DISK* ; Default is DISK1, DISK2,
>   etc.
>
> As MakeCAB processes a directive file, it will create one or more
>   disk "images". Rather than using some specific disk format, however,
>   MakeCAB simply creates one subdirectory for each disk and places the
>   files for each disk in the appropriate directory. If a `*` exists in
>   this variable, then it is replaced with the disk number. If no `*` is
>   specified, then all files are placed in the single directory specified
>   by this variable.
>
> This variable is used only if no variable DiskDirectoryn exists for
>   disk n.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> .Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=C:\EXCEL6\DISK*  ; Put files in separate dirs
> .Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=C:\EXCEL6        ; Put all files in C:\EXCEL6
> .Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=                 ; Put all files in current dir
> ```
>
> **CabinetNameTemplate**=template
>
> Sets the cabinet file name template.
>
> Default: `.Set CabinetNameTemplate=*.CAB ; 1.CAB, 2.CAB, ...`
>
> This template is used to construct the file name of each cabinet. The `*`
>   in this template is replaced by the cabinet number (1, 2, etc.). This
>   variable is used only if no variable CabinetNamen exists for cabinet
>   n.
>
> **NOTE: Be sure that the expanded cabinet name does not exceed the
>   limits for your file system**! For example, if you used "CABINET*.CAB",
>   and MakeCAB had to create 10 or more cabinets, then you would have
>   cabinet names like CABINET10.CAB, which is 9.3, which is an invalid
>   name in the FAT file system. Unfortunately, MakeCAB would not detect
>   this until it had already created 9 cabinets!
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> .Set CabinetNameTemplate=EXCEL*.DIA  ; EXCEL1.DIA, EXCEL2.DIA, etc.
>
> .Set CabinetNameTemplate=*.          ; 1, 2, 3, etc.
> ```

In addition, when files are split across cab (in case if cabinet size exceeds its limit size) then you can set subsequent cabinet filenames also using variable CabinetName*n*:

`CabinetNamen=filename`     [Cabinet file name for cabinet number n]

> **CabinetNamen**=filename
>
> The cabinet file name for the specified cabinet.
>
> Default: ; By default none of these variables are defined
>
> If this
>   variable is not defined for a particular disk, then MakeCAB uses the
>   CabinetNameTemplate to construct the cabinet name.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> .Set CabinetName2=test2.cab
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly where your source files exist, you can generate a file list from the directory:

```
dir C:\FolderName /s /b /a-d > c:\temp\files.txt
```

Then use the files.txt file to create the cab file.

```
makecab /d CabinetName1=test.cab /D DiskDirectoryTemplate=C:\temp /f c:\temp\files.txt
```

The above command will generate a test.cab file in your C:\Temp folder using the file list generated earlier.

*Additional helpful reference:*
[Microsoft Cabinet Reference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx) and 
[makecab.exe details.](https://ss64.com/nt/makecab.html)